# Is it possible to send HTTP request from inside Google docs?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs

I want to send an HTTP request to some REST service from Google drive spreadsheet.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but that sounds like it would have *massive* security implications.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible, check out Google Apps Scripts, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Using Google Apps Script, you can make HTTP requests to [external APIs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external) from inside Google Docs/Sheets/etc. using the [UrlFetchApp class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app):

```
var url = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?'
    + 'q=skateboarding+dog'
    + '&start-index=21'
    + '&max-results=10'
    + '&v=2';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
Logger.log(response);
```

Note that:

> This service requires the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request scope. In most cases Apps Script automatically detects and includes the scopes a script needs, but if you are setting your scopes explicitly you must manually add this scope to use UrlFetchApp.

ref: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

Comment: Looks like function in your Sheet doesn't work anymore.

Comment: The script was added by someone else - it looks like Google now requires that permissions be granted but also the Facebook API he was using is now deprecated.  I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 39):

Yes, you can use `IMPORTDATA`. It's designed to work with CSV data but will load any URL you throw at it:

```
=IMPORTDATA("https://stackoverflow.com/q/23917189/209828")
```

New line characters start a new row in the spreadsheet and the values shown in the cells are referenceable. Put this formula in `A1` of its own sheet and reference cells from different sheets.

[image: Google Sheets showing example usage of IMPORTDATA function]

Comment: Works great for simple GET request.